# Why can white-space character class not be used in Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression that matches fine in tools like [Regexr](http://regexr.com), but I get an exception using that regulare expression in .NET:

```
Regex r = new Regex("[\\w\\.\\{\\},\\+-\\s]*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Does anyone know why the exception is raised? It does not get raised when leaving the **\s** out, but of course then the regular expression does no long match what I want.

Comment: To avoid issues with `-` inside character classes, always put them at the start of the character class. In 99.9% cases, it is safe to use it at the end of the character class.

Comment: Argh... Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. yes, duplicate.

Comment: BTW, my 99.9% means that a `-` at the end of the character class only needs to be escaped in ElasticSearch (Lucene) regex flavor, everywhere else it is ok to be unescaped there.